add_subdirectory(opencv) not working, can not find including header
I build a project based on OpenCV source, here is the basic structure:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0...3.10)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)

project(
    test
    LANGUAGES CXX
    VERSION 0.0.1
)

add_subdirectory(external)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}

    tests/test_start.cpp
    tests/test_contours.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    gtest_main
    opencv_core
)

and in subdirectory external there is another CMakeLists.txt
project(external)

set(BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)

# unzip source inside external directory
add_subdirectory(opencv-4.10.0)
add_subdirectory(googletest)

googletest work fine, but I can't include the header files in opencv2.
Is it any wrong step to use add_subdirectory(opencv-4.10.0) here?
The offical documentation is use find_package, which need to install first?
After add_subdirectory opencv, the build log show building opencv, but print  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} or ${OpenCV_LIBS} is empty.
As a comparison, the googletest is working. I want a correct way to add_subdirectory opencv without install.

EDIT:
Reference to this duplicate question:
c++ - Compile and link OpenCV to my project in my main CMakeLists.txt - Stack Overflow: Compile and link OpenCV to my project in my main CMakeLists.txt
I got an error: fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp' file not found, this file is located in build directory, so it need to add ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} too.
# you can just add modules that you need
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC 
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/calib3d/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/core/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/cudaarithm/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/cudabgsegm/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/cudacodec/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/cudafeatures2d/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/cudafilters/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/cudaimgproc/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/cudalegacy/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/cudaobjdetect/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/cudaoptflow/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/cudastereo/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/cudawarping/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/cudev/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/dnn/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/features2d/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/flann/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/highgui/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/imgcodecs/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/imgproc/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/ml/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/objdetect/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/photo/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/shape/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/stitching/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/superres/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/ts/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/video/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/videoio/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/videostab/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/viz/include
    external/opencv-4.10.0/modules/world/include
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)

I'm not sure if this is best practice, especially using "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}".
Thanks to @Tsyvarev 's valuable explanation.

Googletest project "ships" its public targets (like gtest_main) with include directories. So when linking against such targets you automatically got the include directories. OpenCV project doesn't ship its targets with include directories.
